# Mac OS X - app without menu?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'd like to build an app that does not have a menubar, a dock icon, or sits in the app switcher. Basically, it should be like Quicksilver: I'd active it through a global hot key, say from Safari, and a little window appears, but Safari does not get inactive, neither does a different menubar show. I hope you understand what I mean...

How would I do that? I can prevent the dock icon, the app switcher, but I do not know how I can prevent the other apps from becoming inactive when my app's window shows or how I can remove the menu.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try searching for "`LSUIElement`". That should give you all the information you need.

(Specifically, [this page in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256)).

Comment: I can still only either activate my app's window and deactivate the other app's window, or the other way around...

Comment: @ryyst: You want your app's window to become "key" without becoming "main".

Comment: @Josh Caswell: I do that, but my app's window remains inactive (greyed out). I try to make a `NSTextField` first responder, but that doesn't work...

Comment: @ryyst: You're trying to get around some of AppKit's fundamental built-in behavior; it won't be easy. From a glance over [Quicksilver's source](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-alchemy/), it looks like QS is doing its own event dispatching, i.e. not using the standard responder chain -- they've actually subclassed NSApplication, which is, AFAIK, pretty uncommon.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Well, I'm going to look into that then... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As Dave already said, add

```
LSUIElement  YES
```

in your application's Info.plist file. That will get rid of icon and menu bar.

Then, to actually bring a window to the front at the appropriate time (e.g. when triggered through a global keyboard shortcut), you could do something like this:

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn = {0, kCurrentProcess};
SetFrontProcess(&psn);

[someWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Comment: I want my app's window to come to the front and I want to be able to type in a text field without the app I had open before becoming inactive (i.e. the titlebar becoming light gray).

Comment: Doesn't the above code work for you to do just this? For the text field focus you may need to set the first responder, but the rest should work.

Comment: No, it doesn't. As I said, the other apps become inactive.